# Does anybody have more information about this inventor?

Tags: us20120276518

Does anybody have more information about the inventor for patent application US20120276518?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are impressed with this application's specific contributions or the general field of 3d printing of organic structures.

Regarding this particular document - the file history of this application titled  **Method and Device for Perfusing Tissue by ExVivo Attachment to a Living Organism** says the inventor, John Archie Gillis, is from Halifax Canada.

The application looks like it was done without professional help, to its detriment in my opinion. I have no idea if that is reflective at all about the quality of the science. At this point it is an application that has not yet been examined on its merits (as of Feb. 2013).

Answer (score 1):

See this link to find other inventions from the same guy.
http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?compact=false&ST=advanced&IN=Archie+Gillis&locale=fr_EP&DB=EPODOC

Answer (score 1):

This is one of my inventions (I am Archie)

In my preferred embodiment of the method the patient himself or herself will function as the bioreactor for the development of a neo-organ.  If the patient in need of the organ is not healthy enough, than a healthy human would perhaps volunteer or accept payment to build a donor organ and said patient would function as a bioreactor for someone in need.   I would liken it to someone donating their kidney, but with much less to lose.  The volunteer would need to be a match and the process may be a little risky at first, but over time and with lots of testing I’m sure that we could make it a very safe procedure.

Essentially we would harvest the cells from the person functioning as a bioreactor and then cultivate the cells (and perhaps preserve them) for when we decide to begin the process of fabrication.  This would eliminate all of the immunogenicity issues during the fabrication process.  Once the organ was completed it would be detached from the person functioning as the bioreactor and it would be implanted into the patient that needs the donor organ.  This patient would still require immunosuppressant medication, but they would at least have found the organ that they need.

I’m not sure of the ethical implications of hiring a human to be a bioreactor for a number of weeks or months, but it seems less invasive and somewhat less ethically controversial than asking someone to donate a functional kidney.  There may be some people that would welcome the opportunity to help another human or in some instances earn money for their stay in a medical facility to save a persons (or loved ones) life.